# How do I go back to end of the first line in csv file?

Tags: c++, csv, ofstream

I am using ofstream to write a csv file.
Currently, I am writing it left to right using "<<" operator, which is easy.
For example,

```
Shape,Area,Min,Max
Square,10,2,11
Rectangle,20,3,12
```

I want to change so that it looks like

```
Shape,Square,Rectangle
Area,10,20
Min,2,3
Max,11,12
```

I know I can use "<<" operator and just write it that way, but I am using some loops and it's not possible to use "<<" operator write it like that.

So I am looking for a way to write in the order, for example

```
Shape,
Area,
Min,
Max,
```

Then becomes

```
Shape,Square
Area,10
Min,2
Max,1
```

So It's basically going from top to bottom rather than left to right.
How do I use ofstream to code this? I am guessing I have to use seekp, but I'm not sure how.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure about your "it's not possible" assertion.  If you could include some of your code it would help in forming  a response.

Comment: That seems like a really inefficient way of writing out the file, that's going to have the buffer, or the disk, churning, resizing and shuffling data.  You might want to think about your approach again and change your loops.

Comment: It will be really hard to do with stream (or files). You need to build an internal structure in your code so that you can serialize the data in the order required.

Comment: I realize it is inefficient, but for a quick fix, and for my knowledge of learning how to move around positions in file, I would like to know. The reason it's not possible is because right now the code is in a way which it iterates a square using for loop, and another iteration inside the square to find area, min and max using different region of interest inside the square, and I need to find the min, max, and area for all region of interests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert other than at the end of an ostream without
overwriting already written data.  For something like what
you're trying to do, you probably have to collect each row in
separate string (perhaps using ostringstream to write it), then
output the rows.  Something like:

```
std::ostringstream label;
label << "Shape";
std::ostringstream area;
area << "Area";
std::ostringstream min;
min << "Min";
std::ostringstream max;
max << "Max";
for (std::vector<Shape>::const_iterator> it = shapes.begin();
        it != shapese.end();
        ++ it)
{
    label << ',' << it->TypeName();
    area << ',' << it->Area();
    min << ',' << it->min();
    max << ',' << it->max();
}
dest << label.str() << '\n';
dest << area.str() << '\n';
dest << min.str() << '\n';
dest << max.str() << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old `FILE*` API, `seek`ing as needed.  IOStreams also allow you to [`seekp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/seekp/) and [`seekg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/).  But manipulating files like this will be difficult.  If you write out, say, 100 bytes, `seekp` to the beginning and start writing more data, you're going to overwrite what's already there (it doesn't automatically get shifted around for you).  You're likely going to need to read in the file's contents, manipulate them in memory, and write them to disk in one shot.

Comment: The old FILE* API has exactly the same problem: you can seek to your hearts content, you can overwrite existing data, but you cannot insert.

Comment: That's true.  I didn't make that clear.  My point was only that seeking is supported by the `FILE*` API and the IOStreams API.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough it is inefficient, it could be done by writing fixed size lines (40 characters?) with extra spaces, so you can go to a line and (fixed) position by seeking line*40+position (or look for the comma) and overwrite the spaces.

Now that you have this knowledge, go for the approach as mentioned by Martin